# How to allow multiple select to form:radio buttons that are in loop

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

Hei,

I ran into a problem with my survey application. I display all questions(6) using c:forEach loop and all of them are displayed on a single page. Using the same loop I also display all the textareas for answers. Everything worked great until I got a stupid idea to add radio buttons with values as an answer input for some questions. My code looks like this:

```
            <c:forEach items="${questions}" var="q">


                <p><c:out value="${q.questionText}"></c:out></p>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${q.questionID !='2' && q.questionID !='6'}">
                <form:checkboxes path="answerList" items="${options}"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                <form:textarea path="answerList" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Vasta tähän"></form:textarea>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>


        </c:forEach>
```

As it is all in loop so multiplay radio button rows will be displayed (1 per question) And the problem is that I need to get 1 selected answer in each row. I tried to change form:radiobuttons to form:checkboxes and it worked, but then problem is that user can select multiple option per 1 row. Has anybody ran into the same problem and found an answer? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I got it to work. Needed to simply use checkboxes instead of radio buttons and also one tiny javascript that prevent multiple selection in answer row.